# Issue with Custom Object Detector model from GCP Vision

Tags: ios, tensorflow, object-detection-api, google-mlkit, google-cloud-automl

My full tech stack is:

- GCP ML Vision.
- Exported Model to tflite format (from the same GCP console).
- XCode for iOS development
- iPhone 11 pro

I am trying to use a Custom Object detector using MLKit and one model trained in GCP AutoML Vision.
I created the model and exported as *tflite* file, but when trying to do `objectDetector processImage:visionImage`, I always get the error:
**Error Domain=com.google.visionkit.pipeline.error Code=3 "Pipeline failed to fully start:
CalculatorGraph::Run() failed in Run:
Calculator::Open() for node "BoxClassifierCalculator" failed: #vk Unexpected number of dimensions for output index 0:
got 3D, expected either 2D (BxN with B=1) or 4D (BxHxWxN with B=1, W=1, H=1)."
UserInfo={com.google.visionkit.status=<MLKITvk_VNKStatusWrapper: 0x280841270>, NSLocalizedDescription=Pipeline failed to fully start:
CalculatorGraph::Run() failed in Run:
Calculator::Open() for node "BoxClassifierCalculator" failed: #vk Unexpected number of dimensions for output index 0:
got 3D, expected either 2D (BxN with B=1) or 4D (BxHxWxN with B=1, W=1, H=1).}**.
I have downloaded the mlkit examples from `https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit`and there is something similar in the vision project, (to detect birds) when I try to replace my own tflite file, it breaks in the exact same way as in my own project.
I presume the tflite is created in a very different way as MLVision does.
Any insight? (Sorry if this is so obvious, but I'm pretty new to TensorFlow and MLVision)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is exactly as what the error message says: `got 3D, expected either 2D (BxN with B=1) or 4D (BxHxWxN with B=1, W=1, H=1)`. That means your model is not compatible with ML Kit, as its tensor has incorrect dimension. The model compatibility requirements are specified [here](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models#model-compatibility).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help on this, in short, any model trained in MLVision will work with the default MLKit SDK, I have been able to read it with a class using TensorFlowObjC library though, quite complicated for beginners like me, but I think I finally solve it.